# Find $ T^*\left( \begin{smallmatrix} a&b\\ c&d\end{smallmatrix} \right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, inner-products, adjoint-operators

Let $T:\mathbb{C^3} \to \mathcal{M}_{2x2}$ and $T(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix} 
  3x+iy & y-iz\\ 
  iy+z & 2x
\end{pmatrix}$ with the inner product $<A, B>=tr(\bar{B}^t, A)$.

Find $T^*\begin{pmatrix} 
  a & b\\ 
  c & d
\end{pmatrix}$

**What I've been doing:**

Using the definition for adjoint transformation:

$<(x, y, z), T^*\begin{pmatrix} 
  a & b\\ 
  c & d
\end{pmatrix}>=<\begin{pmatrix} 
  a & b\\ 
  c & d
\end{pmatrix}, T(x, y, z)>$

So using the given inner product and the standart basis:

$<\begin{pmatrix} 
  1 & 0\\ 
  0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 
  3x+iy & y-iz\\ 
  iy+z & 2x
\end{pmatrix}>=tr(\begin{pmatrix} 
  3x+iy & iy+z\\ 
 y-iz & 2x
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
  1 & 0\\ 
  0 & 0
\end{pmatrix})=3x+iy=(3, i, 0)$

$<\begin{pmatrix} 
  0 & 1\\ 
  0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 
  3x+iy & y-iz\\ 
  iy+z & 2x
\end{pmatrix}>=tr(\begin{pmatrix} 
  3x+iy & iy+z\\ 
 y-iz & 2x
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
  0 & 1\\ 
  0 & 0
\end{pmatrix})=y-iz=(0, 1, -i)$

$<\begin{pmatrix} 
  0 & 0\\ 
  1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 
  3x+iy & y-iz\\ 
  iy+z & 2x
\end{pmatrix}>=tr(\begin{pmatrix} 
  3x+iy & iy+z\\ 
 y-iz & 2x
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
  0 & 0\\ 
  1 & 0
\end{pmatrix})=iy+z=(0,i,1)$

$<\begin{pmatrix} 
  0 & 0\\ 
  0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 
  3x+iy & y-iz\\ 
  iy+z & 2x
\end{pmatrix}>=tr(\begin{pmatrix} 
  3x+iy & iy+z\\ 
 y-iz & 2x
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
  0 & 0\\ 
  0 & 1
\end{pmatrix})=2x=(2,0,0)$

And then I found $T^*\begin{pmatrix} 
  a & b\\ 
  c & d
\end{pmatrix}$:

$T^*\begin{pmatrix} 
  a & b\\ 
  c & d
\end{pmatrix}=a(3,i,0)+b(0,1,-i)+c(0,i,1)+d(2,0,0)=(3a+2d, ia+b+ic, -ib+c)$

The given solution was 
$T^*\begin{pmatrix} 
  a & b\\ 
  c & d
\end{pmatrix}=(3a+2d, -ia+b-ic, ib+c)$

Comment: Note that your solution is just the *conjugate* of the given solution. Your very first step seems to exchange the sides of the inner product.